# Counter label in UITableView Cell repeats while scrolling down

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I have counting labels in a tableview cells according to plus and minus button the label value increases and decrease count by one and when i am scrolling down the label is repeating on other cells and data is changing in cells from moving up and down.Anyone please help me with this.Thanks

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:CustomTableViewCell = self.customTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.plusButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.plusButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BtnPlusPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.minusButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.minusButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BtnMinusPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.deviceLabel.text = self.laptop[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

@objc func BtnPlusPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let button = sender as? UIButton
    let cell = button?.superview?.superview as? CustomTableViewCell
    let indexPath = customTableView.indexPath(for: cell!)
    if let text = cell?.countLabel.text, let value = Int(text) {
    var counter = value {
        didSet {
            cell?.countLabel.text = "\(counter)"
            print()
        }
    }
    counter += 1
    callback?(counter)
    }
}
@objc func BtnMinusPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let button = sender as? UIButton
    let cell = button?.superview?.superview as? CustomTableViewCell
    let indexPath = customTableView.indexPath(for: cell!)
    if let text = cell?.countLabel.text, let value = Int(text), value > 0  {
        var counter = value {
            didSet {
                cell?.countLabel.text = "\(counter)"
            }
        }
        counter -= 1
        callback?(counter)
    }
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BakwB.png)

Comment: Cells are reusing. goes out from top, gets in from bottom. and reverse.

Comment: You will need to store the value in your underlying data model, not in the cells themselves. This is because the cells are reused once they scroll off the screen. Set the value based on the data model in the cellForRow() method.

Comment: The counter value should be stored in an array, like your laptop array where you get the data from. The cell should not be where you keep the value of the counter. The value of the counter should be fetched in the cellForRow method - it gets called for every cell about to be reused.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't know what's `callback?(counter)` doing. But I think your problem could be solved, as other people has already said, by storing your counter values along with the datasource. Right now your `counter`property only exists in the `cellForRow`block. 
 Let's say you want all the values start from zero, and your model array is called list. You could do the following:

```
var counters = [Int]()
for i in 0..<list.count {
    counters.append(0)
}
```

and then your method could be like this. I unwrapped the button to avoid dealing with optionals:

```
@objc func BtnMinusPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    guard let button = sender as? UIButton else { return }
    let position = button.tag
    guard counters[position] > 0 else { return }
    counters[position]
    counters[position] -= 1
    cell.countLabel.text = "\(counters[position])"
    }
```

Comment: you did set the button tag in cellForRow, this is how you get the position, and when you do `counters[position] -= 1` you're changing that position in the array

Answer (score 0):

Cells are reused. You have to save the counter value for each cell. But rather than using an extra array use a custom struct as data model

```
struct Model {
    let name : String
    var counter = 0
}
```

Declare the data source array

```
var laptop = [Model]()
```

---

And in Swift a better way as target/action is using a callback. The callback must be declared in the table view cell.

In the custom cell add `IBaction`s and the callback to be able to update the model in the controller. The outlets for the buttons are not needed. Connect the actions to the buttons in Interface Builder.

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var deviceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!

    var callback : ((Int) -> Void)?

    var counter = 0 {
      didSet { countLabel.text = "\(counter)" }
    }

    @IBAction func plusAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        counter += 1
        callback?(counter)
    }

    @IBAction func minusAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if counter > 0 { counter -= 1 }
        callback?(counter)
    }

}
```

In `cellForRow` assign the string value to the deviceLabel and assign also the callback. Whenever one of the buttons is pressed the label and the model are updated.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.customTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! CustomTableViewCell

    let item = self.laptop[indexPath.row]
    cell.deviceLabel.text = item.name
    cell.counter = item.counter
    cell.callback = ( newValue in
        self.laptop[indexPath.row].counter = newValue
    }

    return cell
}
```

Delete also both `Btn...Pressed` actions. the benefit is no view hierarchy math, no tags, no *objective-c-ish* target/action

Comment: No, **one** instance of the model corresponds with **one** string in the array (represented by the `name`property). You have to map your string array to the model